# Howto send signals to a program started in Debug mode in KDevelop

Tags: c++, signals, kdevelop

I want to analyse a program that i've written in KDevelop.
I compile the Program and start it with

> *Right Click on the CMake Project -> Debug as... -> Native Application*

Now the program runs in KDevelop and I can see the output on the console embedded into KDevelop.
My program stops running when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>" (SIGTERM). I can press it when I'm running the program in a console outside KDevelop.

How can I send the signal "SIGTERM" to the embedded console inside KDevelop?

As a workaround I can start **htop**, select the program and send a SIGTERM from there, which works fine although it would be nicer to have all the functionality in KDevelop itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible Solution is:

- Right Click on the CMake Project -> Debug as... -> Native Application.
- Change to the "gdb"-Tab inside KDevelop.
- Hit the "Pause"-Icon on the right corner to enable the input field of the "gdb"-Tab
- Type `signal <Signal>`, e.g. `signal SIGTERM`
- The program continues and it catches the signal sent.

Answer (score 0):

Use the kill command to send a signal to a process. `kill -l` should provide you with a list of signals and their IDs.

For example, on FreeBSD, the SIGTERM signal is #15 as shown by this output:

```
$ kill -l
 1) SIGHUP       2) SIGINT       3) SIGQUIT      4) SIGILL       5) SIGTRAP
 6) SIGABRT      7) SIGEMT       8) SIGFPE       9) SIGKILL     10) SIGBUS
11) SIGSEGV     12) SIGSYS      13) SIGPIPE     14) SIGALRM     15) SIGTERM
16) SIGURG      17) SIGSTOP     18) SIGTSTP     19) SIGCONT     20) SIGCHLD
21) SIGTTIN     22) SIGTTOU     23) SIGIO       24) SIGXCPU     25) SIGXFSZ
26) SIGVTALRM   27) SIGPROF     28) SIGWINCH    29) SIGINFO     30) SIGUSR1
31) SIGUSR2
```

So to send a SIGTERM to my process, I look up the process ID and then send it a kill command like so:

```
kill -15 <process ID>
```

Comment: FYI, I realize that you're looking for a solution from within KDevelop. Perhaps you can at least use this info to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Exactly, i'm looking for a solution from within KDevelop. Pressing Ctrl+C (SIGTERM) isn't recognised by KDevelop's embedded console, that's why im asking for help. Beforehand i used **kill** and Co. ending up with a more comfortable **htop**. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can send SIGINT from inside KDevelop:

Run -> Interrupt

However you can't send any other signal.

If you think that's an useful feature create a wish request on bugs.kde.org - eventually including an attached patch :D

Comment: I wasn't aware of "Run->Interrupt", i always hit "Pause" on the gdb Tab, which seems to be the same. My program is listening to SIGINT SIGTERM & SIGBREAK. Somehow the SIGINT fired in KDevelop seems to be catched by gdb. Perhaps there is the possibility to send a SIGINT or SIGTERM from gdb running my program.